# MDX: use dimension values on columns

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, dimension

I wanted to use dimension properties on columns. So, in the mdx query, I dragged in those properties from the dimension "member properties". But, for some reason, the values for those properties are nulls only. However, if the dimension members are used on rows, they have legitimate values.

Is there any other way, I can pull in those dimension values on columns?

Answer (score 1):

You're not very specific about which properties you want to bring back, but you can always pull back more properties by adding this to you MDX query (assuming this is how you are querying, as it seems you are using a drag and drop editor):

```
SELECT {[YourDimension]} DIMENSION PROPERTIES KEY0,MEMBER_CAPTION ON COLUMNS
```